# How to show a dialog box three days once in an android application

Tags: android

How can I show a dialog box once every three days in an Android application?

Comment: ur question is not clear.Do u want to show dialog after every three days

Comment: dose this dialog appears automatically or on user intreaction with application

Answer (score 2):

Use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html).

Before displaying the dialog check the preferences to get the time that it was last displayed.  If it's been more than three days, display the dialog and set a new time in SharedPrefs.

```
long time = sharedPrefs.getLong("displayedTime", 0);
if (time < System.currentTimeMillis() - 259200000) {
   displayDialog();
   prefsEditor.putLong("displayedTime", System.currentTimeMillis()).commit();
}
```

Comment: I think user is asking for dialog to appears automatically without user intraction with application every after 3 days

Comment: Who is to say?  I interpreted it to mean don't show the dialog more often than 3 days, you interpreted it differently.  We can't read the mind of a very nonspecific OP that originally said: "show a dialog box  three days once."

Answer (score 0):

code flow should be like this

1.Create an [alarmmanger](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) like

```
  AlarmManager alarmanager=alarmanager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
  Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,DialogService.class);
  PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(),0,intent , 0);
  alarmanager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                        System.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY * 3,
                        pendingIntent );
```

2.Create a service DialogService

Here u create dialog in onStartCommand

Comment: I think an alarm manager might be overkill, but it really depends on the use case.

Comment: @eskimoapps.com wat do u mean by overkill and use case..Bcoz alarm works even when cpu is sleep mode

Comment: It's only necessary if you need the event to fire at any time, if you know when you want to show the dialog in the app SharedPreferences will suffice because getting the current time is easy.

Comment: @eskimoapps.com sorry to say ..I think u have not worked with alarm manager

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [alarmmanager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) to trigger the event.